# Rspec Mock/Stub test rails join association add/remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I am new to Mock/Stub, In my Grape API I have following logic where I add @course to the joins association

```
helpers do
  def fetch_site
    unless current_organisation
      error!("401 Unauthorized", 401)
    end
    @site = current_organisation.sites.find(params[:site_id])
  end

  def fetch_certification_course
    @course = Ihub::CertificationCourse.find(params[:certification_course_id])
  end
end


  post do
    fetch_site
    fetch_certification_course
    @site.certification_courses << @course
    present @site.certification_courses, with: Entities::CertificationCourse
  end
```

In Site model I have following relationship

```
has_many :site_certifications, class_name: 'Ihub::SiteCertification'
has_many :certification_courses, through: :site_certifications
```

And how do I use Mock/stub to test this API properly? Specially this part " @site.certification_courses << @course"

This is what I have done for delete join association

The code to test

```
    @site.certification_courses.delete(certification_course)
```

The test

```
  @site = stub_model(Site)
  expect(@site).to receive_message_chain('certification_courses.delete')
```

Comment: How are you currently testing your API? Can you post your existing test/mocks too, please?

Comment: Please find my existing test for delete join association. I don't know how to test adding <<.

Comment: I found the way to test push to array arr.should_receive(:<<).with("a"), but in my case I have this join association "certification_courses", how to mock this?

Comment: You shouldn't test for the implementation details, like for example, if it is added using `<<` method or `push` or something else. Upon posting, you should test something like @site.certification_courses.include?(@course)